# How can i use model in Javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

Example :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function abc() {
            var t = document.getElementById("name").value;
            @foreach(Player pl in Model){
            if (t == pl.Name) {
                alert("This name is already use!");
            }                
        }
    </script>
```

Error : t - cannot resolve symbol 
How can i use JavaScript variable in C# code? Is it possible in this example?

Comment: This is so wrong that I don't know how to explain... You mix server side code with client side code, that is the best I came out with.

Comment: @Aviatrix what made you think it's `Razor-2` code?

Comment: assuming he is new to MVC and he just installed it , it's razor 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use JS variables in C# code , but you can use C# variables in the code.
In most cases  C# is used to render HTML or JS.

In your case it would be best if you render your C# serverside model as a JS array , which you can later on iterate.

1. make an action that [returns your list (assuming it's a list) as
   a JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300820/how-do-i-return-json-from-action-method-with-array-property)
2. [fetch the data with an AJAX get call to your action.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You may do something like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function abc(players) {
        var t = document.getElementById("name").value;
        for(p in players) {
        if (t == p.Name) {
            alert("This name is already use!");
        }                
    }

    abc(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode( Model )));
</script>
```

Comment: Error : Cannot name "Json" in this context